# How to fix AngularJS passing string value as number in JS function parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap 4 Accordion. Each card in the accordion will display "system information" including version number (ng-repeat from systemData object array). My application is set up to store the systems version as a text/varchar (postgres DB) as there could be multiple decimals in the version number (e.g. 6.3.1, 7.1.10, etc.)

I've created a JS function in the angular JS controller to display a particular image if the FIRST char in the version string is "8". However, the browser seems to be sending the param as a number, which is causing the JS function to fail when the version has more than 1 decimal point, because it is receiving param as "NaN".

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Accordion-->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="allSystemsAccordion">
            <div class="card" ng-repeat="system in systemData track by $index">
                <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#systemsAccordionCollapse{{$index}}">
                    <img ng-show="isVersionEight({{system.version}})" ng-src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:30px; border-radius:50%">
                    <a>{{system.version}}</a>
                </div>
                <div id="systemsAccordionCollapse{{$index}}" class="collapse" data-parent="#allSystemsAccordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="text-secondary">Version: </a><strong>{{system.version}}</strong><br>
                        <a class="text-secondary">Owner: </a><strong>{{system.owner}}</strong><br>
                        <a class="text-secondary">URL: </a><strong>{{system.url}}</strong><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The JS Function (within the angular controller)

```
$scope.isVersionEight = function(version) {
        //actual logic will go here, but below is console statements for debugging for now. 
        console.log("FUNCTION VERSION AND TYPE: " + version + " " + typeof version + " toString(): " + version.toString() + " " + typeof version.toString());
    };
```

Note that in the anchor tag below the image tag containing the version, as well as the version listed in the card-body, display on the UI just fine, no matter what amount of decimals are present. Also, if I print the contents of systemData (JSON) in the console, I can see the values for version surrounded by quotes, which makes me believe that the client-side is receiving a string from the server as expected, and setting it as that type.

Here is a screenshot example for an object in systemData:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of what the console outputs when the function is run:

[image]

Why is the system.version value being read as number seemingly only in this function param? How can I get it to be a string BEFORE it gets to my function? I understand I can do a toString() in my function, but this isn't helpful as the argument for my function is already "NaN".

Answer (score 0):

Wow, over-analysis on my part. The fix is embarrassingly simple. 
I changed:
ng-show="isVersionEight({{system.version}})"

to:

ng-show="isVersionEight('{{system.version}}')"

Simply missing the quotes!